# Enumeration access in different class

Tags: c++

I have enumeraion in Class A and class B have class A instance as member.
How can I access Class A enumeraion in Class B using this instance

```
Class A{
   enum ab{
   a 1,
   b 2 };
}
```

IN class B i need to get this enumeraion

Comment: your code does not compile at all, Class should be class, there should be `=` between names and values.

Comment: See also [Declaring an enum within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2503807/96780).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
   public:
   enum ab{
   a= 1,
   b= 2 };
};

class B{
    public:
    void test()
    {
        enum A::ab x=A::a;
        cout << "test A::a = " << x << endl;
        x=A::b;
        cout << "test A::b = " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "A::a = " << A::a << endl;
    cout << "A::b = " << A::b << endl;
    class B b;
    b.test();
}
```

The enumerated names a,b do reside in class A namespace so, you can access them using `A::` prefix like `A::a`.

Comment: can I use A::a to get 1

Answer (score 3):

```
A::ab
```

As long as `ab` is public.

Of course you need to fix the syntax of your enum first.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503807/96780).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class A
{
public:
   enum ab{
   a = 1,
   b = 2 };
}

class B
{
   A::ab myVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You access the type via

```
A::ab;
```

and the values via

```
A::a;
A::b;
```

Of course, this assumes ab is public.