# Two enum with same value, how to access them?

Tags: c++, enums

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum class Rank{ TWO = 2, THREE = 3, FOUR = 4, FIVE = 5, SIX = 6, SEVEN = 7, 
                EIGHT = 8, NINE = 9, TEN = 10, JACK = 10, 
                QUEEN = 10, KING = 10, ACE = 11 };
    Rank r;

}
```

Is it possible to access TEN, JACK and Queen without using `Card::Rank::TEN Card::Rank::JACK` `Card::Rank::QUEEN Card::Rank::KING`?

I am overloading `ostream operator<<` using a `switch`, but it has errors...
when i try to create a constructor initializing 52 cards in class Deck, I find it impossible.

Comment: Please show the part that does not compile, otherwise we may end up helping you solve a wrong problem.

Comment: Side note: Is this for blackjack? Ace's can be 1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no difference between `Card::Rank::TEN`, `Card::Rank::JACK`, `Card::Rank::QUEEN` and `Card::Rank::KING`. You cannot tell them apart.

It's the same as if you wrote

```
#define TEN 10
#define JACK 10
#define QUEEN 10
#define KING 10
```

And then programmatically trying to distinguish between them. But they contain the exact same value; they are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

A switch with several branches on the same value is erroneous. An enum value is just a fancy way to write an integer, so...

Answer (score 0):

In terms of having to type `Card::Rank::TEN` according to one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503807/declaring-an-enum-within-a-class) you should be able to use `Card::TEN` instead, provided you declare your `enum` like this:

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum Rank { TWO = 2, THREE = 3, FOUR = 4, FIVE = 5, SIX = 6, SEVEN = 7, 
                EIGHT = 8, NINE = 9, TEN = 10, JACK = 10, 
                QUEEN = 10, KING = 10, ACE = 11 };
```

You can't use two of the same values in a `switch` statement no matter what. This is because when the code runs and you get a value `10` your code will not be able to determine if it is a Ten, Jack, Queen or a King.

Either change the values or use only one of them in your switch. Here is a contrived example:

```
int function(int value)
{
    int rv = 0;

    switch (value)
    {
        case 0:
            rv = 7;
            break;
        case 1:
            rv = 8;
            break;
        case 1:
            rv = 21;
            break;
        default:
            rv = 0;
            break;
    }

    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    printf("What does function(1) return? %d", function(1));

    return 0;
}
```

This would not make sense since we return two different values when we are passed the value `1` so the compiler does not allow it.

It is the same if you use your `enum` values of `Card::Rank::TEN` in the switch because their **value** is the same the compiler doesn't allow it.

```
Card::Rank card = Card::Rank::TEN;

switch(card)
{
    // Some cases...
    case Card::Rank::JACK:
        // Do something
        break;
    case Card::Rank::TEN: // <- not allowed since it is the same as the case for Card::Rank::JACK.
        // Do something else
        break;
    // Some more cases...
}
```

This isn't allowed. The following would seem like it *should* be ok since the compiler *should* be able to see that it is the same code being run for both cases but it still won't work.

```
switch(card)
{
    // Some cases...
    case Card::Rank::JACK:
    case Card::Rank::TEN: // <- still not allowed, even though both code paths for case 10 do the same thing...
        // Do something else
        break;
    // Some more cases...
}
```

and I'm sorry but I can't give good reasoning for this other than, it is probably not allowed in the standard itself for consistency. Someone else might be able to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can view enum as an aliases mechanism. So we usually use it to replace a magic number.

Thus we don't need to write something like`int card1 = 11;` what is 11? We know JACK, and don't know what is 11.

The other advantage is that it limit the possible value and wont see something like `int card2 = 14;`

So in this view point, if J, Q and K have a same value, it would be strange because they are not presenting the same card. If you want to map a card to a value, then std::map is a good choice.

```
enum Rank{ TWO , THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX , SEVEN, ......};


static const std::map<Rank, value> = 
{
    {TWO, 2}, {THREE,3},......
};
```

if as  d_ominic mentioned, the ACE has two value, maybe you would like to try `std::multimap`