# How to use enum class without a scope

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums

I need to use the enumerator of the enum class multiple times in one block of code and I would like to avoid the classical enum from C++03.

```
enum class Color {RED, GREEN};
{
    Color::RED //this works
    RED;       //how do I make this work (only for this block)?
}
```

I tried using

```
using namespace Color;
```

but it obviously did not work since Color is not a namespace.

Comment: Try and look at this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503807/declaring-an-enum-within-a-class

Comment: That Q does not answer my question though.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible:

> `7.3.3p7` **The `using` declaration** `[namespace.udecl]` ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))
>
> > A *using-declaration* shall not name a scoped enumerator.

You can create a type alias using `decltype`:

```
using RED = decltype(red);
```

It *does* work in Clang, but is a [reported bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9124).

The workaround is to use a variable.

```
Color red = Color::RED;
```

---

Rereading the question, it sounds like you want to bring *all* of the enum's variables into scope, not just one member. I suggest you read the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf) for `enum class` to see some of the issues it was trying to solve. The whole point of scoped enums is to avoid injecting its members into the enclosing scope.

So just use a regular enum.

Comment: Well thats a bit cumbersome. Moreover I cant use that in a switch statement like I wanted to.

Comment: @Slazer You can make `red` constexpr.

Comment: I can not use regular enums, because i have two enums and both of them have one enumerator with the same name. I use one enum in one function and the other in another function. I want to use it because of type safety (2.1 in the proposal). I dont want any "color++" or "color=3" going on.

Comment: @Slazer `color++` or `color=3` wouldn't work on a regular enum either.

Comment: I know but one can override that with -fpermissive, which one will do. In C++11 its a showstopper. This was just one reason though. The problem would not be solved with enums anyways as I said.

Comment: @Slazer Hmm, `-fpermissive` doesn't allow it on either GCC or Clang. Perhaps you have an buggy compiler? Even then, it's not really good practice to allow non-conforming code to compile (especially if it's from the "permissive" option). I think the underlying issue is in how your program is written rather than the choice between enum and enum class.

Comment: It will make a warning from the error in MinGW 4.9.1. I can not use "enum" at all though. I have to use "enum class". I still do not see a solution to my problem.